# Passing multiple Job Parameters when running a bootRun Task

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm studying the Spring Boot Batch.

But when I tried to pass the batch parameters in the bootRun Task, it didn't work.

##### Example project

- https://github.com/mklinkj/QnA/tree/master/Spring-Batch/pass-args-in-spring-batch-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I ran the command below...

```
gradle clean bootRun --args='param1=1,param2=2'
```

I expect both `param1=1` and `param2=2` to be passed as Job parameters, but only `param1=1` is passed.

In the batch application, the following exception is thrown because you set the required parameter values for both param1 and param2.

- Exception Message

  ```
  Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException: The JobParameters do not contain required keys: [param2]
  ```

However, when I ran it directly as a jar, there was no problem.

```
gradle clean bootJar
java -jar .\build\libs\pass-args-in-spring-batch-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar param1=1 param2=2
```

- Success when running as a Jar

  ```
  21:13:58.776 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=JobParamTestJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{param1=1, param2=2}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 39ms
  ```

  - In this case, both parameters are passed well.

Is there anything else I need to add in the `build.gradle.kts` file below?

- https://github.com/mklinkj/QnA/blob/master/Spring-Batch/pass-args-in-spring-batch-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl/build.gradle.kts

Thank you. Have a nice day.